# Iterate through directory structure over ssh using python

Tags: python, ssh

I want to iterate through a directory structure over a server I can ssh to (using python).

How can I adapt the code below to first ssh to remote server and then iterate through directory structure and copy over all the .nc (netcdf) files I find.

```
for sub_dir, dir_list, files in os.walk(remote_dir):
    for fl in files:
        if fl.endswith('.nc'):
            # Copy file over to local machine
            print fl
```

thanks!

Comment: Does the server support python? If it does it seems it might be easier to write a script and run it on the server.

Comment: It does, and you are right, it would be a lot easier to just do it on the server. However, I want to copy over stuff to a local machine to do some processing on a software not available on the server.

Comment: It's a bit of a hack but could you have the server side python script output values to the terminal that you could then copy and paste into a file on your side for a different python script to analyse?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to copy over entire files (these are pretty huge).

Comment: Okay I gotcha. I'm no expert on SSH but this could be a good place to start working with python & SSH. I believe it has .get() and .put() commands in addition to SSH capabilities so it should be able to do what you need: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysftp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at spur (https://github.com/mwilliamson/spur.py):

```
import spur

shell = spur.SshShell(hostname="remoteserver", username="bob", password="password1")
with shell:
    result = shell.run(["find", "/", "-name", "*.nc"])
    print result.output
```

If you'd prefer other ssh alternatives, check out https://wiki.python.org/moin/SecureShell